# Using Array Attribute Type in Sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm looking to use the sails attribute type 'array' in my app, but I can't find documentation for this anywhere.

I'd like to do the following:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes : {
  images: {
   type: ['string']
  },
  location: {
   type: ['float','float']
  }
 }
}
```

image is an array that will hold a list of image urls and location will hold 2 floats. Will this work in sail's? Else how can I get this to work.
Thanks

PS: I'm working solely with MongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only specify it like this:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes : {
        images: {
            type: 'array'
        },
        location: {
            type: 'array'
        }
    }
}
```

See [Sails ORM Attributes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes)

Comment: The type "array" is no longer supported.  To use this type in your model, change
`type` to one of the supported types and set the `columnType` property to a column type supported by the model's adapter, e.g. { type: 'json', columnType: 'array' }

Answer (score 5):

As of Sails 1.0 type **array** is no longer supported.

> The type "array" is no longer supported.  To use this type in your model, change
> `type` to one of the supported types and set the `columnType` property to a column
> type supported by the model's adapter, e.g. { type: 'json', columnType: 'array' }

**SOLUTION ONE**

Set up property to store an images array and a location array...

```
module.exports = {
  attributes : {
    images: {
      type: 'json',                           
      columnType: 'array'
    }
    location: {
      type: 'json',
      columnType: 'array'
    }
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION TWO**

A more elegant solution is to set up a single object to store both filename and location data

```
module.exports = {
  attributes : {
    images: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your controller you would store object properties as arrays...

```
let imageData = {
  filename: ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"],
  location: [154.123123, 155.3434234, 35.12312312]
};

Images.create({images:imageData});
```

Some issues when storing data to the json object is that a string like "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg" will store in MongoDb no worries... doh. Ensure that when POSTing you may need to split the data `.split(',')`.

Answer (score 4):

sailsjs provide a function to solve your question,you can try this

```
module.exports = {
 attributes : {
  images: {
   type: 'string'
  },
  location: {
   type: 'json'
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer for future visitors.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is intended to work. The `images` attribute is supposed to be an array of strings but you have just `string`. Also from location's syntax, this specifies that it's value can either be `float` or `float`

Comment: sorry , im just edditing my post for solve your prob

Answer (score 1):

For sails 1.0, for array maybe you can try this way i'm using just for sharing.
Also you can replace before update and process native query() and delete the attributes for updating by waterline. Hope this help you.

```js
        variants:
        {
            type: 'json',
            columnType: 'array',
            custom: (value) =>
            {
                /*
                  [
                        code    : unique, string
                        name    : string, maxLength[30]
                        cost    : number, isFinite
                        price   : number, isFinite
                        default : boolean
                  ]
                */
                return _.isArray(value)
                &&     _.every(value, (variant1) =>
                {
                    return _.countBy(value, (variant2) =>
                    {
                        return variant2.code == variant1.code ? 'eq' : 'uneq';
                    }).eq <= 1
                    && _.isString(variant1.name) && variant1.name.length < 30
                    && _.isNumber(variant1.cost) && _.isFinite(variant1.cost)
                    && _.isNumber(variant1.price) && _.isFinite(variant1.price)
                    && _.isBoolean(variant1.default);
                });
            },
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use type as `ref` for arrays and objects.

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  images: {
   type: 'ref'
  },
  location: {
   type: 'ref'
  }
 }
}
```